# hardware requirement for hadoop installation on Laptop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hardware

What is the best Laptop hardware recommended for installing Hadoop on windows? I assume I have to install a single node installation, if not please guide me for the correct configuration.

Comment: Take a look at http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hadoop2OnWindows for windows installation (without cygwin). Doesn't really have a list of system requirements, but I when you download hadoop as specified on the site, the download has a README (BUILDING.txt) that has the system requirements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know you mentioned wanting to install on Windows, but Cloudera is offering single-node Hadoop Linux VM images that can get you up and running in no time. You even have examples and scripts included, it's a very good place to start.

https://www.cloudera.com/downloads.html

(Don't forget to look at the [Getting Started](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-10.html) section.)

In my opinion, if you want to learn about Big Data and Hadoop, you should also invest some time in familiarising yourself with Linux, as most of the real environments out there are Linux-based.

System Requirements: Per Cloudera page, the VM takes 4GB RAM and 3GB of disk space. This means your laptop should have more than that (I'd recommend 8GB+). Storage-wise, as long as you have enough to test with small and medium-sized data sets (10s of GB), you'll be fine. As for the CPU, if your machine has that amount of RAM you'll most likely be fine. I'm using a single-node crappy Pentium G3210 with 4GB of ram for testing my small jobs and it works just fine.

Later if you outgrow this environment you can simply move to your own pseudo-distributed setup.

Of course, if what I just said makes no sense to you, then you have some reading ahead...

Comment: links are dead - current version is 5-4 (and so old url is not working). if someone's intrested, see https://www.cloudera.com/content/www/en-us/downloads.html and then choose current version

Comment: If I want to set up a cluster for training purpose - say 30 folks at a time just to give them a feel of the system (it will be mostly Hive) - what kind hardware should I be looking for the NameNode and the DataNode? How many data nodes should I ideally aim for? I am not looking at crunching lot of data. It is just for the experience and training.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to practice simple programs (not data intensive) then 4GB RAM should be good. 
If you want to install a Single Node, the best config would be 32GB RAM with 4 cores at least.

For further information on how to install a single node, refer to myhobbyandexperiments.wordpress.com

Answer (score 1):

It is unlikely you're ready to have a Linux-only laptop.  Therefor, you need a 64-bit CPU that supports 64bit virtualization - and of course 64-bit OS. Mind you support for virtualization is often disabled on BIOS level, you'll need to find and enable it.

Other than that, plenty of RAM - at least 8GB, although 16GB is preferred. I also like to have different hard drives for different OS, so a laptop where you can replace DVD with an HD caddy, and a second SSC hard drive (say 128GB) would be good.

Answer (score -4):

Windows 64 bit OS with 4 GB ram should do good.
I have posted a blog. In this blog I have recorded detailed steps with supported screenshots to install and setup Hadoop cluster in a Pseudo Distributed Mode using your Windows 64 bit PC or laptop

This is a 3 step process

Step 1 – Install VM Player

Step 2 – Setup Lubuntu Virtual Machine

Step 3 – Install Hadoop

http://hadooppseudomode.blogspot.in/

Comment: The question is about hardware requirements, not really about installation instructions.